# Is it possible for Javascript to execute Ruby script on VPS/remote server?

Tags: javascript, ruby, database, execute

Would it be possible to create a system which executes a Ruby script on a VPS (according to what is entered in a client-browser) and then retrieve the data from the Ruby script or database?

Many thanks.

Comment: No I haven't - how would it function using AJAX? Using an XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX. There is a tutorial on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and other places if you search. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("exampleDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

If you use jQuery or a similar library, the code would be a but simpler, but this will work. Between this example and the tutorial, I think you will be able to make it work. You can just plug in your URL and change the line that handles the response to whatever you need. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a JS script to call and get the result of a ruby script hosted on a remote server.

You can do that with AJAX. Using the `XMLHttpRequest` or a higher-level library like jQuery, you can make a JS script send requests to the ruby script over HTTP and get back the result.

The script could respond with data in the JSON format for instance.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest.